# How to add additional param to url after successful login

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

After successfully logging in into a Keycloak realm with openid-connect protocol and response type code, Keycloak will redirect the browser into the redirect uri plus param `session_state` and `code` (https://{redirect_uri}/?session_state={session_state}&code={code})

How to let Keycloak server add an additional param to the url? is it needed to create an SPI?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I found the solution for it.

If your OIDC server support additional params, you can setup forward param and retrive in when redirecting back. Or you apply my solution:

I used AuthNote to store the custom param (custom Authenticator and add it into the registration/authentication flow) before redirect to OIDC and retrieve this value after user login successfully (check ODDC config and select suitable flow).

For more details, you can follow this discussion: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/add-more-information-when-login-with-idp/22070